# Use caching for generated BufferedImages in this situation?

Tags: java, swing, caching, jscrollpane, bufferedimage

I am implementing a board game where each player has several units and each unit is shown to a user using a common image which I read from a file using the following method. I read this image at application startup and going to use it later.

```
    private static BufferedImage readBufferedImage (String imagePath) {
        try {
            InputStream is = IconManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(imagePath);
            BufferedImage bimage = ImageIO.read(is);
            is.close();
            return bimage;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Units differ with various colorful tokens located on the top of that common image.**

Before I just add several commonImages to JPanel and tokens were implemented using JLabels which were floating on the top of commonImage

```
    //at startup
    ImageIcon commonImage = new ImageIcon(readBufferedImage("image.png"));
    ...
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(commonImage);
    panel.add(commonImage);

    //located JLabels with token on the top of each commonImage
```

However, now I want to use JScrollPane instead of JPanel, so I think it is a better approach to drawString() and drawImage() to each commonImage before I show it to a user.

I estimate roughly a number of units as 20. So now every turn for every unit I would need to generate on-the-fly separate BufferedImage with various tokens configuration.

**The question is whether I should cache already generated BufferedImages depending on token configuration to extract from cache if the image has been generated before with same configuration?**

Comment: You're repaints will be faster if you can cache some or all the results.  For example, you could generate the a `BuffereImage` of each token and paint that, plus the common image on each path.  Because the common image is a shared resource, it would better (IMHO) try and only keep one copy (rather then combining the image and text into a single image) - This of course comes down to the number of units and there sizes.  The memory trade off for generating a single image for each unit as apposed to just there "token" might be negotiable. You consider how easy it is to paint either method as well

Comment: "it would better (IMHO) try and only keep one copy (rather then combining the image and text into a single image)" - @MadProgrammer but how to implement this? I have done with JLabels floating but since now I put everything in ScrollPane it would be complicated to move JLabels accordingly when scroll happens and hide some of them when common image becomes invisible because of scroll.

Comment: The scroll pane will take care of it for.  I fact, you could dump you existing panel into the scroll pane and resize the game board as you need and the screen pane will take care of it for you.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, you are right, it would happen if I do combine background-common image and tokens into one image. If I don't (floating token) it does not really take care of it.

Comment: The scroll pane acts as a "window" into your component.  So, if you component was 1000x1000 pixels, and you only want to show a window of 100x100, the scroll pane will actually take care of it all for you.  It uses a very clever update process to ensure that only the area that is visible is actually painted.  You can, of cause, check the `Graphics` clip rectangle as well and make sure you're only updating elements that are actually within the view, but as far as you game board should be concerned, it's always visible, all the coordinates are relative to it (500x500 is still 500x500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you ask depends on a few factors:

1. How long it takes to generate the image from scratch
2. How long it takes to check if the image was generated before
3. How large each image will be
4. The probability of the image being reused

So without having a good knowledge of your application, no one is going to be able to give you an answer accurate for every situation.

In general, if you're only moving tokens around, it should be quick to implement an `update` and the `paintComponent` method of the panel your drawing.  If you save your base image, token image and the current resulting image (basically what you proposed), I wouldn't anticipate a performance problem.  The key is to do your updating of the image in your custom `update` method, and always draw the current resulting image in the `paintComponent` method.

**Update**

For example, you can cache the current display using code similar to this:

```
private BufferedImage cachedImage;
...

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    //If the image needs to be refreshed draw it to the cache first
    if(cachedImage == null){
        cachedImage = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
        super.paintComponent(cachedImage.getGraphics());
    }

    //Draw the image from cache
    g.drawImage(cachedImage, 0, 0, this);
}
```

When you want to clear the cache, in your method that does the update, you'd set `cachedImage = null;`

But in your situation,

- Any performance problems at the scale of 200x200 you experience would have to do with the number of drawings you're doing.  Since I'm guessing you're not concerned about a frames/second rate, I doubt you'll have performance problems (you can collect timings to see exactly how long it takes to draw - I'd guess well under 100 ms)
- The easiest thing to do would be cache the images of the tokens and their strings (I'm assuming they rarely change), but still dynamically create the layout of the tokens. (Any other performance gains in your situation aren't going to be so easy).
- Caching previous rendering of the screen will essentially break the swing display model (not much point in using it - just do the layout yourself).  This actually applies to pretty much any caching of a container.

Comment: 1. it is Graphics.drawString once and max 10 times of Graphics.fill(new Rectangle()) or Graphics.draw(new Rectangle()) for each unit complete image. Maximum 20 units.
2. I think it is short time if I save them in HashMap
3. Max 200x200
4. For small number of tokens probability is high and decreases with number of tokens increasing

Comment: Currently I am not using update and paintComponent methods at all. I just use JLabel.setIcon(icon); How those methods can help me?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov added updates to the answer to address some of your questions.  In regards to your 2): You need to have a way to look up images in the hashmap - so you'd have to build a big key and then look it up in the hashmap (which may be more overhead than it's worth).  

Basically you have to look at how much you'd be improving the user experience.  If it takes 100ms, a user probably won't even notice the delay (still assuming you're not doing animations).  On top of that, your likelyhood of using the cache decreases as you need it more (more tokens) - a good argument not to do it.